# gcc -fsanitize=address results in an endless loop on program that does nothing

Tags: gcc

## gcc version

gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

## system type

Linux pop-os 6.6.6-76060606-generic #202312111032~1702306143~22.04~d28ffec SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon D x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## gcc options

-Wall -Werror -pedantic -fsanitize=address

## command line

gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -fsanitize=address main.c

## libraries linked to

- linux-vdso.so.1
- libasan.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6
- libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
- libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
- libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
- /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

## contents of main.c

```
int main(void) {}
```

When the resulting a.out is run, I get an endless loop of:
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

However, it only happens some of the time. For example, it almost always runs 5 times in a row fine, but then after that it starts to break.

Comment: Can reproduce with clang 16 as well, seems like a bug within AddressSanitizer itself...

Comment: I can also reproduce on Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 6.5.0-26 g++ version 11.4.0. Fixed with @Danogentili 's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by an increase of the default value of `vm.mmap_rnd_bits`:

> This value can be used to select the number of bits to use to
> determine the random offset to the base address of vma regions
> resulting from mmap allocations on architectures which support tuning
> address space randomization. This value will be bounded by the
> architecture's minimum and maximum supported values.

On some operating systems like Arch, this value was recently bumped to 32, while ASAN only supports a maximum of 28 randomized bits (30 with some recent, not-yet-released fixes).

Setting the value to 28 will fix the issue: `sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_rnd_bits=28`

See https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1716 for the related discussion.